# Testing forked ruby gems/plugins on GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This seems like a simple question but I haven't found an answer anywhere.

I forked this gem on GitHub: https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator and git cloned the fork to my local machine.

I haven't made any changes to it yet, but want to figure out how to run the tests on it so when I do change it I can make sure they still pass.

It looks like it uses rspec and there are some rspec files in spec/sitemap_generator.  So I tried running `rspec spec/sitemap_generator/*` but I get this:

```
barmstrong:sitemap_generator$ rspec spec/sitemap_generator/*
/Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require': no such file to load -- rspec/core/mocking/with_mocha (MissingSourceFile)
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:164:in `mock_framework='
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:123:in `mock_with'
    from /Users/barmstrong/NetBeansProjects/sitemap_generator/spec/spec_helper.rb:22
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:56:in `configure'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:29:in `configure'
    from /Users/barmstrong/NetBeansProjects/sitemap_generator/spec/spec_helper.rb:21
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/barmstrong/NetBeansProjects/sitemap_generator/spec/sitemap_generator/interpreter_spec.rb:1
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
    from /Users/barmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rspec:19
barmstrong:sitemap_generator$
```

Running `bundle install` or `gem install mocha` didn't seem to help.

I'm not very familiar with rspec (normally just use `rake test` to test rails apps with ActiveSupport::TestCase).  Any suggestions?

Comment: The `Rakefile` has a `spec` target which runs the RSpec examples and a `test` target which builds the gem, install it and then runs the RSpec tests on *that*. Do they also not work?

Comment: Jörg you were right, `rake test` did what I wanted.  Didn't think to check this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment Jörg posted above led to the right answer.  Simply running `rake test` did what I wanted.  Whoops!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `bundle exec` to run Rspec. It looks like just doing `rspec` runs version 2.5.1 installed on your system, whereas doing `bundle exec rspec...` should run the 1.3.0 version of Rspec that the gem's `Gemfile` requires.

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```